# proving subspace of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $W = \lbrace A \in M_n(\mathbb{R}) \mid \operatorname{Tr}(A) = 0\rbrace$ where $\operatorname{Tr}(A)$ is the trace of $A$ (i.e. equal to sum of diagonal elements of $A$).

Show that $W$ is a subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

What I tried

I tried to construct a matrix $M_3$ e.g. $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 5 \\
0 & -4 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$$

And try to prove that the sum of any two elements of $W$ is also in $W$ but I can't see how that is true. Then I was going to prove that an element of $W$ under scalar multiplication also produces an element in $W$, but I encountered a similar problem. And obviously I know $W$ is a subset of $M_n$.

Help?

Comment: **Hint:** The nullspace (kernel) of any linear transformation is a sunspace.

Comment: @Raton : There are not two distinct traces of the same matrix. The point is to show that if the traces of two matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$ are both $0$, then the trace of their sum is $0$ and the trace of the product of either of them with a scalar is $0$. To show that a set is a subspace is to show that it is closed under addition of two members, and that it is closed under multiplication of a member be a scalar.  If you add any two matrices whose trace is $0$, you get a matrix whose trace is $0$, and if you multiply any matrix whose trace is $0$ by a scalar, you get a matrix whose trace is $0$.

Comment: That is what you need to show. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Okay thanks; that makes a lot more sense, idk why I was misreading the question. :)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : I would think a person who understands your comment would probably not be asking this question in the first place. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : Could you approve the recent edit proposal?  I've already done so. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: true . . . (lol)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prove a subspace you need to show that the set is non-empty and that it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, or shortly that $a A_1 + b A_2\in W$ for any $A_1,A_2\in W$.

- The set isn't empty since zero matrix is in the set.
- Let $A_1,A_2\in W$, then $\operatorname{Tr}(a A_1 + b A_2) = a \operatorname{Tr}(A_1)+b \operatorname{Tr}(A_2) = 0+0=0$ therefore  $a A_1 + b A_2\in W$ and you done.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29

Comment: "close to" can be construed as meaning "in proximity to".  The standard locution here is "closed uner".  Subspaces are closed under addition and scalar multiplication. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I think he meant "closed under"

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks !

Comment: And it's pretty intuitive b/c Tr is just addition after all -- Thanks!